# Find maximum value from while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, max

I'm fairly new to python, and trying to find the max value from a while loop, I've tried making a list but that doesn't seem to work, here is my code, any help appreciated!

The idea of it is to fire a projectile at a user entered velocity at a user defined angle, using equations of motion, the vertical and horiziontal distances are then calculated and plotted. So far the plots show accurate results however when I try to find the maximum height, it just gives me the last value of the while loop. I've tried making a list and finding the max value from that but it gives me only the last value again.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math

print("This programme finds the maximum distance that a projectile travels when fired from ground level at an initial velocity.")

print("")

print("Air resistance is negligible")
u= float(input("Please enter the initial velocity: "))

#print(u)

a = -9.81 
xv=0.0
xh=0.0
t=1.0
ang= float(input("Please enter the angle of fire, between 0 and 90 degrees: "))

rad=((math.pi)/(180))*(ang)
uh=(u)*(math.cos(rad)) 
uv=(u)*(math.sin(rad))
print(rad, uh, uv)
while range (xv>=0):

    list=[]
    xv = ((uv)*(t))+((0.5)*(a)*(t)*(t))

    xh = (uh)*(t)
    vv=uv+(a*t)
    vh=uh

    t=t+1
    xv = max(xv)

    plt.plot(xh,xv)
    plt.scatter(xh, xv)
    if xv<=0:
        break

print(list)

print("")
print("The maximum height is", max(xv) , "m, with a flight time of", t, "s")
print("")
print("The velocity when the projectile lands is",vv,"m/s" )


plt.xlabel('Horizontal distance (m)') 

plt.ylabel('Vertical distance (m)') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Critical: fix the indentation. Nice: get rid of the excess whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the help, please excuse my poor stackoverflow etiquette. Hope the edits help.

Answer (score 1):

You may prepend while loop with

```
max_xv = 0
```

Put following line inside the loop

```
max_xv = max(max_xv, xv)
```

Then use `max_xv` as a maximum value

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* use keywords as variable names - here, `list`

You can initialize the list of heights before the while loop starts:

```py
heights = []
```

then `append` values as you go through the loop (there are other ways to do this but using your structure...)

```py
    heights.append(xv)
```

and after the loop finishes you can examine using `max`

```py
print( max(heights))
```

Putting that together, the middle of your program might look like:

```py
print(rad, uh, uv)
heights = []
t = 0.0
while xv >= 0:
    # plot this point
    plt.plot(xh,xv)
    plt.scatter(xh, xv)
    # save height
    heights.append(xv)

    # calculate next point
    t += 0.1
    xv = uv*t + 0.5*a*t*t
    xh = uh*t
    vv = uv + a*t
    vh = uh

# xv has gone negative so loop has finished
print (max(heights))
```

(I reordered, improved the loop to exit properly and reduced the time increment)